# PL/SQL REGEXP_LIKE testing string for allowed characters

Tags: regex, oracle, plsql

I need to verify that the provided string has only allowed characters using Oracle regular expressions (REGEXP_LIKE). 
Allowed chars are: abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789_-.
Trying to execute

```
SELECT CASE 
         WHEN REGEXP_LIKE('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789_-.'
                        , '^[a-z0-9_\-\.]+$') 
         THEN 'true' 
         ELSE 'false' 
END tmp 
FROM dual;
```

results in 'false'.

Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
SELECT CASE
          WHEN REGEXP_LIKE ('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789_-.',
                            '^([a-z]|[0-9]|_|\-|\.)+$')
          THEN
             'true'
          ELSE
             'false'
       END AS tmp
  FROM DUAL;
```

Does that fix it for you?
(I'm not in front of a PC to test this i'm afraid)

EDIT:

FWIW this below should remove all valid characters leaving you with only those that were invalid if you needed to see what had caused the string to fail your validation:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE ('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789_-.',
                       '([a-z]|[0-9]|_|\-|\.)+',
                       '') AS tmp
  FROM DUAL;
```

You could test for cases where the return was `NULL` which would be valid and where it wasn't null you could return the invalid characters in the validation error message.

Hope it helps...

Answer (score 0):

the dash "-" must be the first element between right brackets [], and backslash have no particular meaning between []

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN COUNT(REPLACE((TRANSLATE('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789_-.',
                                       'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789_-.',
                                       ' ')),
                            ' ',
                            '')) = 0 THEN
          'TRUE'
         ELSE
          'FALSE'
       END AS CHECK_RESULT
  FROM DUAL
```

This query will return false in case any character exists not among the predefined list.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Inside a character class any symbol `'-'` in the middle is being treated as *meta character (meaning range from left to right symbol)* so the class `[a-z0-9_\-\.]` doesn't allow `'-'` to appear in source_string. The  way to correctly put `'-'` into character class as a symbol is by placing it at the first or the last position in the character class.

Also there's no need to escape `'.'` with a slash when it's in a character class, but your variant doesn't violate syntax.

Any of the following regular expressions give what you're expecting:

```
variant_1 => '^[-a-z0-9_.]+$'
variant_2 => '^[a-z0-9_.-]+$'
variant_3 => '^[a-z0-9_\.-]+$'
```